# How to track a 3d object in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to implement an AR app with 3d object tracking. I have gone through the vuforia qualcomm sdk. But it provides tracking of objects with predefined shapes(cuboid,cylinder) etc. Is there any other AR sdk which provides real time 3d object tracking.? I have also tried metaio sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing an APP based on augmented reality and let me tell you that Vuforia's is the best option to do it. I've been searching for the best SDK, but Vuforia's offers you a lot of features and makes you easier the development in "low level" (via C++) or "high level" (via Java Native Access, JNA).

Changing the model could be a bit difficult using Java Vuforia version.

Here you are a tutorial which explains you how you could do it:

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/java-replacing-teapot-without-jna

**Attention**

I know I committed a mistake when I did the document. Just for the case you decide to follow it: When you have your tree separated files, you have to remove all comments before parsing them.

In Notepad++ (for example), you can delete these comments replacing with a regular expression like this:

```
"//(.)*".
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial for replacing the teapot. But i want to track an object and not an image. But vuforia target manager now supports only cuboid and cylinder like shapes. So how can i track an object like camera or irregular objects.?

Comment: I've not developed with this feature yet, sorry. I recommend you to use the official forum of Vuforia. Many times the same developers of Vuforia are directly answer our questions!! I hope you could get the solution ;)